# Intersecting Path cancel each other out in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, pdf

I have a really weird issue in Illustrator and I can't imagine that I am the only one who stumbled across this.
I am trying to make a standardized icon set for use in Powerpoint. Other people working with this icon set should be able to recolor the icons. Therefore I am only working with strokes and I don't use fills.

One of the icons looks like this:
[image]

The path width in the picture above is 4pt (so extending 2pts on both sides of the vector line). The buttons for the controller have a vector-line-diameter of less then 2pts. Therefore there is an overlap.

When exporting to either PDF or SVG I get the following result:

[image]

The result looks like this in **all** pdfs, **but** the SVG only looks like this in Powerpoint and in the MacOS preview of *Finder*. If I open the SVG in Google Chrome it looks as expected:

[image]

It seems like the intersection of the path results in the intersection to be removed. I think this is a render issue. Has anyone ever experienced this issue and knows how to solve this?

Comment: Yes it is common that different rendering engines behave differently. This is one of the reason final drawings are usually expanded. Dä

Comment: Curious why they are strokes and not simply fills.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I would suggest you use filled circles instead of a stroke.  I can't honestly see the point of creating solid circles with a stroke. Even more so if it's not rendering properly in some software.

Comment: Take the controller above as an example. Imagine I would make the controller buttons solid fill but kept the outline of the controller as a path. If one of my coworkers now inserts the SVG in PowerPoint and changes the fill color, then the entire controller gets a fill instead of having a transparent fill because it is a complete shape. So either I make everything a fill or I make everything a path. I can't think of any other solutions. I would generally also prefer to have the stroke to be resizable in powerpoint. If I use fills, I cannot do that.

Comment: @joojaa what do you mean by expanded? Do you mean that strokes are outlined?